# From Illustrator to png with the help of ImageMagick

Tags: adobe-illustrator, imagemagick

Currently I save my files in Illustrator as `.pdf` files so that I can use [ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imagemagick) to manipulate the resulting images programatically (cropping, adding borders, resizing, etc) and convert them to `.png` (the format that I eventually need all my images on).

The reason why I edit my files in Illustrator in`.pdf` as opposed to `.ai` is because, as far as I understand, ImageMagick does not support `.ai` directly.

However, when I choose to save an Illustrator file in CS5 as a `.pdf` file while keeping editing compatibility on, the background seems to lose its transparency, or at least that's what I see when I ask ImageMagick to convert the `.pdf` file to `.png` with

```
mogrify -alpha "on" -background transparent -format .png file.pdf
```

since I can easily check the transparency on the `png` file.

So I am wondering two things:

1. Is there a way to directly check if the background on a `.pdf` file is transparent? This would help me diagnose the problem of losing background transparency in my `.png` files, since at the moment I have no way of checking if the background transparency is lost in the process of saving Illustrator files as `.pdf` (as opposed to `.ai`), or in the conversion from `.pdf` to `.png`.
2. As I said earlier, I usually save an my illustrator files in `.pdf` mostly because I can then  use ImageMagick to convert the resulting file to a `.png` and still keep the ability to make changes on a file that supports Illustrator's objects and features almost natively.

   However, I am wondering if there is a different path to get a `.png` from an `.ai` file using ImageMagick while preserving background transparency and the ability to fully edit the original objects in Illustrator.